# Error while running springboot test due to org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, java-stream, junit4, spring-boot-test

I have two junit tests which extends an abstract Class

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
//Config implementations
}
```

```
public class abstract TestA {
// common implementation
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(TestConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfile("test")
public class TestB extends TestA {
// Tests
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(TestConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfile("test")
public class TestC extends TestA {
}
```

> When I run the test classes TestB and TestC following error occurs
>
> > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> > at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
> > at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
> > **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.properties'
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:526)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:475)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:445)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
> > at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
> > at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:424)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:323)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:204)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:178)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
> > at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
> > at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
> > Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
> > at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
> > at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.(ReferencePipeline.java:94)
> > at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$StatelessOp.(ReferencePipeline.java:685)
> > at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3.(ReferencePipeline.java:187)
> > at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.map(ReferencePipeline.java:186)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.asDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:555)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:545)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:499)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:475)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:445)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
> > at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:427)
> > at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:424)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:323)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:204)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:178)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
> > at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
> > at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
> > at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
> > at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
> > at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
> > at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
> > at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
> > at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)**

could some please help me here why this error occurs?

Comment: There might be some properties defined in application.yaml or application-env.yml which resides in main/resources and you might have missed to define the same properties in test/resources which you might be using in code with @Value or some other way

Comment: Do you have a github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a problem with property `spring.profiles.active`, please check it's value in application.properties or application.yaml

Comment: I didn't use the "spring.profiles.active" in my application.properties

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)` in `TestB`, and `TestC` class.

I have created a project and ran successfully, and uploaded in GIT on the below repository path,

https://github.com/thangavel-projects/stack-overflow-test

Just clone and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your test enviornment is not right. Please redefine your `Test Class`

I woud rather use a `pulic class TestBase{}` for the others test class to extend.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(TestConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfile("test")
public class TestBase {

}
```

And the other Class use as followed:

```java
public class TestC extends TestA {
    @Test
    public ......
}

public class TestB extends TestA {
    @Test
    public ......
}
```

The configuration like this is simple and less error will occur.